# VBA excel generate any random number

Tags: vba, excel

I just learning VBA in excel and just want to know how to generate any random number using I believe RND function.

Comment: perform a search....

Comment: I've only seen random number in ranges/between. I just want any random number.

Comment: You cannot have "any" random number, since numbers in computers are limited in range (albeit those ranges are rather large). Random functions (almost) always returns a number between 0 and 1. You can then multiply that number, with your upper limit (e.g. `Rnd * 1000`) to increase the range.

Comment: The Related topics suggestions on the right hand side of this page may also be useful to check out.

Answer (score 0):

Say we want to randomly pick a number from **any number** that Excel can represent *(positive or negative)*.

- The largest positive value in Excel is 9.99999999999999E+307
- Multiply this by `Rnd()` should generate a random value between 0 and the max
- Then randomly pick the sign *(+-)* of the result:

```
Sub Randum()
    Dim a As Double, b As Double, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    a = 9.99999999999999E+307

    Randomize

    b = wf.Choose(wf.RandBetween(1, 2), -1, 1) * Rnd() * a

    MsgBox b
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to focus on the concept of general numbers in computer science, rather than the more abstract understanding of random. In computer science, random numbers (almost) always start out, as a number between 0 and 1. You can then multiply it, to increase the size of the range and add/subtract numbers to change the offset.

```
'Example of using Rnd in VBA
Sub RandomPrint()
    Dim rand As Double
    rand = Rnd * 49 + 1
    rand = Round(rand)
    Debug.Print "Random integer between 1 and 50: " + CStr(rand)
End Sub
```

https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/rnd.php

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2(v=vs.90).aspx